# Echo string showing escaped characters

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to echo a string showing the escaped characters in powershell? I am looking for something similar to the `repr` function in python. I would like to use this for debugging.

For example:

```
>>$var="abc`ndef"
>>echo $var
```

Output:

```
abc
def
```

Desired output:

```
"abc`ndef"
or
abc`ndef
```

Answer (score 2):

This will unescape the ` replacing it with a \

Hence the `-replace` at the end:

```
$var="abc`ndef"
$var = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Escape($var) -replace '\\','`'
echo $var
```

Output:

```
abc`ndef
```

Comment: This works pretty well, except that it escapes more characters than powershell.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not what you want, but will work fine :)

```
function Get-EscapedString([string] $String) {
  $escape = @{
    "`0"='`0';
    "`a"='`a';
    "`b"='`b';
    "`f"='`f';
    "`n"='`n';
    "`r"='`r';
    "`t"='`t';
    "`v"='`v'
  }
  $str = $String
  foreach ($char in $escape.Keys) {
    $str = $str -replace $char, $escape[$char]
  }
  $str
}
```

Comment: I think that should instead be called Get-EscapedString because you are escaping the special characters.

Comment: @dan-gph Thank you!  I fixed it :P

Answer (score -1):

Surround the string with single-quotes and the escape sequences won't be interpreted:

```
"abc`ndef"
```

outputs

```
abc
def
```

but

```
'abc`ndef'
```

outputs

```
abc`ndef
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. I am inspecting an already existing string.